# Rotating background images effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background

How can I create a background image rotating effect similar to the effect on [this website](http://trump.com)?

It uses flash but I want to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it using [this plugin](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)

Comment: In the future, it will help if your questions are more specific.  Clicking on the link you provided, it is not immediately clear what you mean by "background rotating effect."